# What are those variations of norms called?

Tags: reference-request, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space with a function $\|\cdot\|$ on it that satisfies all the axioms of norms except for scalability condition $\|\alpha \mathbf{x}\| = |\alpha| \|\mathbf{x}\|$ replaced with $\|\alpha \mathbf{x}\| = |\alpha|^m \|\mathbf{x}\|$, where $m$ is a fixed positive integer?

What if the scalability condition is instead replaced with $\|\alpha \mathbf{x}\| = |\alpha|^{m(\mathbf{x})} \|\mathbf{x}\|$ where now $m$ is some positive integer function of $\mathbf{x}$?

Do those "norms" have names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a function $m$ satisfies your condition, then $m(x) = 1$ for all $x \ne 0$. Just observe the following inequality:
$$2^{m(x)}||x|| = ||2x|| = ||x + x|| \le ||x|| + ||x|| = 2||x||$$

Comment: Right! BTW, what if the function only preserved scalar multiplication up to a power? That is, $f : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(\alpha x) = |\alpha|^{m(x)} f(x)?$$

Comment: If $m$ is constant, then such a function is called absolutely homogenous of degree $m$. I'm not aware of any special name if $m$ is not constant.

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot.